# Using the straight braces in math time pro

Tags: fonts, mtpro, mathtime

I am using the free lite version of mathtime pro font, and I was hoping if there is a way I could use the computer modern version of curly braces ({}). Mathtime pro has its own curly braces which are rounder, but since I am using the free version, it doesn't come with extra large versions of them.

I was wondering, is there a way that I can selectively replace the mathtime curly braces with the computer modern's more straight ones?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean: if I try `$\begin{Bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \\ 4 \\ 5 \\ 6 \end{Bmatrix}$` (requires amsmath) I get straight braces covering the whole matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see too big a difference:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareSymbolFont{cmlargesymbols}{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\cmrbrace}{\mathclose}{symbols}{"67}{cmlargesymbols}{"09}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\cmlbrace}{\mathopen}{symbols}{"66}{cmlargesymbols}{"08}

\begin{document}

\[
\text{MTPro2:}
\quad
\left\{\begin{matrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \\ 4 \\ 5 \\ 6 \end{matrix} \right\}
\qquad
\text{CM:}
\quad
\left\cmlbrace\begin{matrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \\ 4 \\ 5 \\ 6 \end{matrix} \right\cmrbrace
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to replace the MTPro2 braces with CM ones

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareSymbolFont{cmlargesymbols}{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\{}{\mathopen}{symbols}{"66}{cmlargesymbols}{"08}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\}}{\mathclose}{symbols}{"67}{cmlargesymbols}{"09}
\let\lbrace\{
\let\rbrace\}

\begin{document}

\[
\text{MTPro2:}
\quad
\left\{\begin{matrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \\ 4 \\ 5 \\ 6 \end{matrix} \right\}
\qquad
\text{CM:}
\quad
\left\{\begin{matrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \\ 4 \\ 5 \\ 6 \end{matrix} \right\}
\]

\end{document}
```

I left both instances, but now in either case the CM braces are used, just for comparison with the previous picture.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Some large symbols (and more others could be added) are in the computer modern font in the following codes.

```
\documentclass{article}
                                            
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
%invoke computer modern large symbol font
\DeclareSymbolFont{mylargesymbols}{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}
%large left and right braces 
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\lbrace}{\mathopen}{symbols}{"66}{mylargesymbols}{"08}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\rbrace}{\mathclose}{symbols}{"67}{mylargesymbols}{"09}
%large left and right parenthesis
\DeclareMathDelimiter{(}{\mathopen}{operators}{"28}{mylargesymbols}{"00}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{)}{\mathclose}{operators}{"29}{mylargesymbols}{"01}
%left and right brakets
\DeclareMathDelimiter{[}{\mathopen}{operators}{"5B}{mylargesymbols}{"02}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{]}{\mathclose}{operators}{"5D}{mylargesymbols}{"03}
%large above and under braces
\DeclareMathSymbol{\braceld}{\mathord}{mylargesymbols}{"7A}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bracerd}{\mathord}{mylargesymbols}{"7B}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bracelu}{\mathord}{mylargesymbols}{"7C}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\braceru}{\mathord}{mylargesymbols}{"7D}
%large left and right groups
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\lgroup}{\mathopen}{mylargesymbols}{"3A}{largesymbols}{"3A}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\rgroup}{\mathclose}{mylargesymbols}{"3B}{largesymbols}{"3B}
%large left and right braceverts
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\bracevert}{\mathord}{mylargesymbols}{"3E}{largesymbols}{"3E}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
See 
\[
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
x^2&x\leq 0,\\
x^3+9&x\geq 0.
\end{cases}
\]
and see
\[\underbrace{x\times\cdots \times x}_{n\text{ many}}=x^n.\]
\end{document}
```

[image]